# .htaccess allow upload to directory, prevent download

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

What is the best and most secure way to let users upload a file to a directory and disallow  the download of these file from any user/client. Download of the file should only be possible by ftp-client.

Or should I move the uploaded file from the upload directory to another .htaccess-protected folder by php-script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put a .htaccess in the directory with the following content:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Every access from the internet is now impossible, so no downloads are possible. Since the upload is managed with PHP (I assume since you mention it), it's still working fine, because the .htaccess doesn't affect the access of PHP scripts to this directory (`move_uploaded_file()` is still possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can take this approach using `<Limit>` directive to:

- allow PUT method and use PUT for uploading
- disallow GET, POST, DELETE methods

For example add this in in `uploads/.htaccess file`:

```
<Limit POST GET DELETE>
    deny from all
</Limit>
```